# Copy an image src and place in url

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image in my site and I want to dynamically use this src as a background image on a inline style on the header url.

```
<div class="banner"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" /></div>

<header style="background:url(*image-from-banner*) no-repeat;"></header>
```

I found this code which does what I want but backwards, can someone help reverse it for me.

```
$('.banner img').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).find('img').attr('src',href);
});
```

Comment: Images don't have `href` attributes. And `$(this).find('img')` won't find anything, because `$(this)` is the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background image for the `<header>` like:

```
$('header').css('background-image', 'url(' + $('.banner img').attr('src') + ')');
```